# What happens if I reached the limit of my sendgrid plan?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I want to use sendgrid for sending password recovery emails and get the free version with the limit of 100 emails a day. I couldnt see what happens if that limit is reached. What if there is a user who during that day requests password recovery but it would be email number 101? would he just not be able to send it? Do I need to set up something myself on my backend? Would I be charged for the next plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you pass the SendGrid emails limit, in your case (free version) - 101 email, you will get:

1. The 101 email will get rejected by the Sendgrid API.
2. SendGrid API will return a rate limit error response ([status code 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)).
   You can handle this error in your code, and you might consider sending the email through a different service or trying again later when the limit refreshes.